# Loading a large sparse martix in Python crashes

Tags: python, sparse-matrix

I'm using `csr_matrix` in Python to load a **~3GB** sparse data set (a few million colmuns and a few ten thousand rows) on a 16GB RAM system.

I have three lists: rows, columns and values and I use the following line to load the matrix:

```
A = csr_matrix((listOfValues, (listOfRows, listOfCols)))
```

However the upload fails (I saw that it uses ~15GB of RAM before it crashes).

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How many non-zero elements do you have? In other words: what's the length of listOfValues?

Comment: @physicalattraction: 343M. All entries are "1", but Python is unaware of that